# what's islamic view on arabization?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis

i am an egyptian muslim

okay so my country is having an identity crisis all because of arabization and that the fact we aren't arabs then i proceed to tell them that infact islam have nothing to do with arabization at all infact i am not even sure that both are compatible and i even proceeded to tell them that it's not permissible for muslims which were the arabs to arabize anyone because muslims generally must respect the laws of the land they enter and also i read that it's forbidden to be named under another  ethnic group or tribe which you don't belong to here is the link of another article about it but it's in arabic

https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/277771/%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%84%D8%BA%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%84%D8%A9-%D9%88%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A9-%D9%85%D9%86%D9%87

muslims which were the arabs at the time weren't allowed to wash identity or ethnic ties away and i proceed to tell them that even arab muslims at the time actually expanded for religious reasons not for the sake of arabization both have nothing to do with each other at all and i told them prophet muhammed never saw us egyptians as arabs in the first place but infact saw us as a separate group and there is a hadiths where he refers to egyptians/copts as a separate people

their defence was the following 
telling me that arabs are not an ethnic group but you actually become an arab by language and culture and some even said the prophet muhammed wasn't an actual arab (my response to that was speaking a language or knowing some of it's culture cannot make you a part of a separate ethnicity or tribe because both are infact changeable at any time )

they also told me that they didn't consider egyptians as arabs before egypt was culturally and lingustically wasn't arabized yet and he said that it's hilarious that i am citing the prophet , who claimed to be a descended from an iraqi man and egyptian woman whose tribe were arabized but that didn't stop his arabized tribe from being called the most honorable of the arabs

so where is the truth in all of this and what's islamic ruling on arabization and it's attack on separate identities , cultures , ethnic ties and it erases  everything

Comment: This argument sounds similar to the one made by some of my Indian friends. They say one is a "Hindu" not just by religion but because of the fact that he/she lives across the Hind river (today called Indus)

Comment: Arabization is fine as long as it doesnt contradict with the limits set by Allah

Comment: @Rafid it went way beyond that limit along time ago ! we are suffering from an identity crisis and we don't know our culture and history and identity and even caused many other problems even ethnicity even most of us think we came from arabs when we did not or even they give it an excuse to justify it of how we became arabs when arab muslims came to egypt , arabization is toxic and a cancer and i want my country's identity and culture back and i want my country back from this invasion it completely erased everything that we actually are

Comment: @user35377 then tell me what makes arabization in your country is contradicting with islamic rulings, your question is still vague on the contradiction itself

Comment: @Rafid  it erased everything that  makes us who we actually are i edited the past comment explaining even more

Comment: @user35377 hmm, every culture will eventually change (some are disappeard), as long as the change/disappearance is not contradicting with islamic rulings, thats fine

Comment: @Rafid ours was pushed to change and disappear it didn't happen naturally !

Comment: @user35377 then blame the people that broke the rules, no need to blame islam

Comment: @rafid well who is going to pay for what we are going through today?

Comment: people that break the rules of islam

Comment: @Rafid maybe it's better if islam or the arabs never came at that point